# Значение разговорного фразеологизма "заносит на поворотах"

Tags: фразеология

Ни в каких словарях не нашёл, а фразеологизм такой в разговорной речи довольно распространён:

> его/её **заносит на поворотах**

Что это означает?

Comment: Помню моя сваха приходя с работы говорила : Такая голодная, аж заносит на поворотах XD

Answer (score 3):

**Смысл устойчивого выражения:** На поворотах машину заносит, она становится неуправляемой.  Некоторых людей тоже "заносит", они слишком увлекаются разговором, неожиданной ситуацией и начинают вести себя неосмотрительно, говорить то, что не стали бы говорить в другое время, в другом месте (а затем жалеют об этом). Короче говоря,  они тоже становятся **неуправляемыми**.

Это предостережение людям, для которых характерно такое поведение.

Answer (score 2):

> Ни в каких словарях не нашёл, а фразеологизм такой в разговорной речи
>   довольно распространён:
>
> его/её **заносит на поворотах**.
>
> Что это означает?

.

В словарях есть другой фразеологизм:

> [**Осторожнее на поворотах**](http://phraseology.academic.ru/7942/%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85)
>
> Прост. Экспрес. **Будь осмотрительнее в выражениях, поступках и т. п.**
>   (как предостережение, предупреждение). *Чертёжника сняли с поезда, а
>   молодой человек в кандалах подмигнул ему напоследок и посоветовал быть
>   «осторожнее на поворотах»* (Паустовский. Повесть о жизни).
>
> Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель,
>   АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008.

.

В сопоставлении с этим фразеологизмом **его/её заносит на поворотах** означает примерно следующее:

**он/она проявляет неосмотрительность в выражениях, поступках и т. п.**

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в "Словаре народной фразеологии". 
 (Кузьмич В. Жгучий глагол: Словарь народной фразеологии". Изд-во "Зеленый век", 2000. )

"Яйца на поворотах заносит".
 Говорится при потере человеком координации, невозможности вовремя повернуть при движении.

Понятно, что ради приличия первое слово не произносится,  в разговорной речи прижилось только окончание полной фразы.